# binary comparation

Tags: c++, binary

Is there any function in c++ to convert decimal number to binary number without using divide algorithm?
I want to count different bits of binary format of 2 numbers. like diff(0,2) is 1 bit. or diff(3,15) is 2 bit.
I want to write diff function.
thanks

Comment: What do you mean *"convert"*?  Any number is *already* in binary format, you are confusing display with how it is actually stored.  Remember though; if you're going to perform bitwise operations on a floating point number you need to know how they are stored.

Comment: numbers are stored in binary format, no need to convert.. Btw you are looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance.

Comment: I know but is this any way to show binary format of number without divides algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the number of different bits by counting the bits in the xor of the two numbers.
Something like this.

```
int count_bits(unsigned int n) {
    int result = 0;
    while(n) {
        result += 1;
        // Remove the lowest bit.
        n &= n - 1;
    }
    return result;
}

int diff(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    return count_bits(a ^ b);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this work? I can't understand count_bits(a ^ b) how run?

Comment: I'm sensing that this is homework - you might want to explain that more :p

Comment: @Ava that's XOR. I explained what it means in my answer.

Comment: a ^ b is the bitwise xor of two numbers. The xor of two bits is 0 if the bits are the same, and 1 if they're different, so counting the number of bits in a ^ b is exactly the number of different bits in a and b.

Comment: PS: I was very happy to use &=, it's pretty rare to have a use for it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use XOR on the numbers ( if Z = X XOR Y then each bit which is set differently in X and Y will be set to 1 in Z, each bit that is set the same in X and Y will be set to 0), and count the bits of the result using a simple loop and shift.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is already in binary technically.  You just need to start looking at bitwise operators to access the individual bits composing the decimal numbers you're looking at.

For example,

```
if (15 & 1) would check to see if 15 has its first bit turned on.
if (15 & 3) would check to see if its first 2 bits were turned on.
if (15 & 4) would check to see if its 3rd bit only was turned on.
```

You can do this with and/or/xor/etc.  Google bitwise operators and read up.